# Why does imageview not show the image of the same size as it was given?

Tags: android, layout, landscape, portrait, stretched

I aplogise for the sparseness of detail but this is something most likely to be immediately obvious to someone.

I've added an `ImageButton` to a page layout and this displays fine when it's loading from layout-land but in layout-port the same thing is stretched upwards. The size of the image is being hardcoded to a particular value so I don't see how it can possibly be stretched.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, android GUI component adjust itself as per screen resolution.

In portrait mode the height of the screen is changes and that why your button image is look like stretched vertically.one solution for this is to use high-resolution images or changing the layout as per screen rotation.

Also have a look at [android-supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: But how are you supposed to maintain a size with that?